# Can quadrics be applied to the n-body problem?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, dynamical-systems, classical-mechanics, chaos-theory, celestial-mechanics

Gravitational orbits within the 2-body problem can be visualized as conics on the surface of a double cone. Is it reasonable to imagine that 3-body systems can be visualized as quadrics on the surface of a double (or perhaps triple) hypercone? Furthermore, is it reasonable to extend this idea of orbits in n-body systems as being quadrics on the surface of some number of even higher dimensional hypercones?

If this idea isn't complete nonsense, would it be useful computationally?

There is no closed form solution to the n-body problem, and most n-body orbits are non-repeating, so perhaps that means that they cannot be described with quadrics.

There's a 2013 paper titled [Conic Sections Beyond $\mathbb{R}^{2}$](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiQo-Oupez1AhVfg3IEHQXvAe4QFnoECAQQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.whitman.edu%2FDocuments%2FAcademics%2FMathematics%2FHandlin.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2_6vykovR0ismHUg9naIM0) which talks about quadrics, but it's purely in the geometric sense.

If this is better suited for the physics stackexchange, I'd be happy to delete this and ask there.

Comment: Have you tested your question on [known solutions to the 3-body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem#General_solution)?

Comment: I tried to answer my own question by reading everything I could, but my understanding of mathematics is only at a linear algebra level (from my bachelors in computer science). I wasn't sure if I couldn't see a clear link between this question and anything I saw online because the question is stupid, or if the question is answered in a way that I just don't understand, or perhaps the answer isn't so obvious.

Comment: You basically have the idea when you write, "There is no closed form solution to the n-body problem, and most n-body orbits are non-repeating, so perhaps that means that they cannot be described with quadrics."

Comment: I suppose that's all there is to it, then. It's a bit unsatisfying to me. I'm left wondering why adding a third body suddenly makes the entire system change into chaos theory and lose their orbits' simple way of being described geometrically.

Comment: I'm afraid you have to get into the nitty-gritty of the differential equations governing the motion, if you want to understand where the chaos comes from.